# Working with GeoIP - Hadoop Java maven Map Reduce Job

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, mapreduce

i have a file containing ip address and the hour of visit .
which look like that :

```
200.168.1.1 , 10:00
200.168.1.1 , 10:30
320.168.1.1 , 12:00
421.144.2.2 , 10:00
```

i need to create a new file with new value for each ip (location from ip)
A.k.A GeoIP
writing the location how to i achive it using map reduce job using Java Maven ?

Comment: What u had tried till now ? Please share ur code.

Comment: i dont know where to begin : i have found this link http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cgeoip
but i dont know how to interact with this jar that will return a country by ip .